# SparkR subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, sparkr, databricks

I am not able to reproduce the error here, but I am getting an error while running SparkR code on Databricks. All I am trying is something like this.

```
sparkdaraframe <- sparkdaraframe %>%                              
  SparkR::mutate(var1 = ifelse(sparkdaraframe$var2 > sparkdaraframe$var3, 1, 0))
```

With few dataframes it works perfectly fine, but with others it throws an error:

```
Error in ns[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

I tried restarting the cluster and cleared state and results, but no luck.

How should I make it work all the time.

Comment: What happens when you do `sparkdaraframe %>% SparkR::mutate(var1 = ifelse(var2 > var3, 1, 0))`

Comment: It throws an error Error in ns[[i]] : subscript out of bounds. When I used dplyr instead it works. What going on here?

Comment: Old thread, but I found that removing the "mutate" and just doing df$var1 <- ifelse(sparkdaraframe$var2 > sparkdaraframe$var3, 1, 0) works.

Comment: Thanks John! Appreciate your response!